# awk example for print at bottom line

Tags: awk

I have this text, how can i take only the number of year and user ?

for example:

List of Linux user:

2019 100

2018 99

2017 98

2016 97

List of Window user:

2019 100

2018 99

2017 79

```
This is my text
Hello World
Please help me, thank you.
----------------------------------
This is for awk example

List of user Linux
----------------------------------
 Year Ubuntu Debian User
 2019     19     10  100
 2018     18      9   99
 2017     16      8   98
 2016     14      7   97

List of user Window
----------------------------------
 Year Win10 WinServer User
 2019   10        10   100
 2018    8         7    99
 2017    7         7    79
```

EDIT: Adding OP's efforts which OP has put in order to solve his/her own problem and mentioned in comments section.

```
awk 'BEGIN {/List of user Linux/} {print $1 " " $4} END {/List of user Window/}' Input_file
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, we encourage users do add their efforts in their post which they have put in order to solve their own problems. Could you please do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply, i have tried `awk 'BEGIN {/List of user Linux/} {print $1 " " $4} END {/List of user Window/}' ` but seem like my begin and end is wrong so it can not take the data in the middle of them. How can i filter this ?

Comment: Good that you had tried code, when you will add your efforts always in your post you will get good guidance for your question. I have answered to this now, kindly check once and let us know then.

Comment: Thank you, i will add my efforts to next question, sorry for slow respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '!NF{found=""} /List of user Linux|List of user Window/{found=1} found && !/^-/' Input_file
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply, i it work for me i added more `{print $1 " " $4}`, and it work, sorry for this question.

Comment: Hi, can i ask one more question about this topic, thank you. How can i take only value of year ?. i have tried `awk '!NF{found=""} /List of user Linux|List of user Window/{found=1} found && !/^-/ {if(NR>2) print $1}' Input_file`
Seem like NR take from first line of text not the output, what should i do ?. for the output 
2019
2018
2017
2016
2019
2018
2017

Comment: @BìnhBùi, Code which you showed should work IMHO. Sorry I didn't get it where are you getting issues here, kindly do let me know. If possible I would like to encourage you to open a new thread so that for future users it will NOT be a confusion about question and its answer.

Comment: Haha, i have been blocked by this question, see you in next 3 day

Comment: @BìnhBùi, Blocked? but why so? I didn't get it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, i can't ask too much question in 1 day, i am still new in SO.

> You have reached your question limit

Comment: Big thank to you, i will try my best in next 3 day, if i can't do it, i will open new question. One more time, thank you for your reply, cheers.

Comment: @BìnhBùi, Your welcome, my pleasure helping, enjoy Learning on this great site, cheers.